# Trigger Rules when Ubercart order is edited

Tags: 7, rules, ubercart

I am trying to figure out how to trigger a rule when an Ubercart order is edited (for example, when an admin user views the order, clicks the edit tab, changes some info on that page, and then clicks the "Submit Changes" button). I have tried the "Order Status Gets Updated" event, but that only works when you update the status itself on the order's "View" tab (which, of course, is what it is supposed to do). The admin could Edit the order, and then View it and update its status, but I'd like to remove the status update step to streamline this process.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to trigger a rule in this fashion?

Thanks!

Comment: how about updating content? not sure if it triggers in uberkart, but it is content being updated.

Comment: No, unfortunately that seems to only apply to nodes, and not to orders. Thanks, though.

Comment: Does the https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_rules module give you any more options?

Comment: No, that module is only for Drupal 6.